# Adding custom validation with multiple values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a validator to check whether users' inputs contain special characters($%*^). This one works well, but I need to add more special characters in the if statement. I have tried putting the "||" between them, but it didn't work.

```
app.directive('ngHasSpecialChar', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel'
        , link: function (scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
            function myValidation(value) {
                if (value.indexOf("$") < 0) { //How to put other chars here?
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('hasSC', false);
                } else {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('hasSC', true);
                }
                return value;
            }
            mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: not clear if this is what you are asking, but do you want a regex here? eg, `value.match(/[\$%\*\^]/)` might work. http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html (validating user input can be surprisingly complex, it might help to describe the goal of this validation as well)

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thanks